# What practical use is knowing the extrusion direction for a piece of polycarbonate?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, material-science

I noticed after cutting this piece of polycarbonate that there is an extrusion direction indicated. Can that be useful for cutting or other downstream use?

[image]

Comment: It's likely stronger in that direction.

Comment: There may be less polymer cross-linking in the cross-extrusion direction. There may also be some tendency to polarisation of light.